# Better URL formatting with Custom Post Types and Taxonomies

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm using Toolset Types and wondering how easy it is to set up the URL's how I want.

I have a custom post type of venues and I have a custom category taxonomy of location.

Currently the urls are coming out like

```
http://domain.com/venue/location/manchester/
http://domain.com/venue/manchester/the-venue-name/
```

But I want the URL's to be structured like

```
http://domain.com/manchester/
http://domain.com/manchester/the-venue-name/
```

Where do I need to look to make these changes?

Is this all .htaccess work or can something be done within the permalinks section?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe this is possible, although I do not have an exact answer for you at the moment.  Check out the codex page if you haven't already, it might be useful: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: That's a loaded question. Yes, it's possible. You'll be using the rewrite-api and it's ... ever so much fun! 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-rewrite-api-the-basics--wp-25474
http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-rewrite-api-post-types-taxonomies--wp-25488

Comment: Also, check out the following & notice this line in the regist_post_type arguments: array('slug' => 'prodotto/%brand%','with_front' => false) https://wordpress.org/support/topic/insert-category-of-taxonomy-between-custom-post-type-and-post

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right, this hack must work in your template. 
First of all we have to remove the **Post type** name from **url** **Slug**.

```
function ft_remove_postType_slug_fromUrl( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( 'venue' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }
    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'ft_remove_postType_slug_fromUrl', 10, 3 );
```

But this is not gonna work by itself. If u pate this code in your functions.php u should get 404 Error.Bbecause WordPress only expects **posts and pages to behave this way**.

So, you have to add this action also.

```
function ft_change_parsingRequest( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'venue', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ft_change_parsingRequest' );
```

After this, you renew / refresh yours post type / permalink tree (It calls flush_rewrites i guess.), It means, re-update your permalink settings on your admin panel area.

Or if you want to see or do some magic, you can check it out from source url.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1454

This Line says;

```
add_permastruct( $post_type, "{$args->rewrite['slug']}/%$post_type%", $permastruct_args );
```

Happy Coding.